# Try to make a redirection with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect a link such as http://198.54.7.120:8080/api/licence/azedf-ykht-tjyk-tykgt to a link leading to a php file such as http://198.54.7.120/projet/cryptage/frontend.php in a .htaccess file on my server. I want to do this to make sure that I have control over sending requests to a database to retrieve a license, and that it is not the API that does it.

I have tried the following code but nothing conclusive

```
RedirectPermanent http://198.54.7.120:8080/api/licence/15205c3c-8fc5-4e70-916e-5d7a231079d3 http://198.54.7.120/project/cryptage/frontend.php
```

Comment: The RedirectPermanent rule you configured does not match what you put in your question.  You want to redirect everything /apo/licence/* ?  Make sure you **1** loaded the redirect module **2** setup logs and change LogLevel to something high (like trace8) so you see what error messages are generated.  **3** Your Apache must listen on both 8080 and 80 
 **4** and have VirtualHost configurations for both.  **5** RewriteEngine on.

Comment: The documentation of the `RedirectPermanent` clearly states, that the first argument is a _URL-path_ , not a URL: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectpermanent

Answer (score 0):

You could try in /api/licence/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =8080
RewriteRule ^15205c3c-8fc5-4e70-916e-5d7a231079d3 http://198.54.7.120/project/cryptage/frontend.php [L,R]
```

Or if you have control over your server, you could try this in apache2 conf file vhosts.conf or alike:

```
<VirtualHost 198.54.7.120:8080>
#
# ...
#

RedirectPermanent /api/licence/15205c3c-8fc5-4e70-916e-5d7a231079d3 http://198.54.7.120/project/cryptage/frontend.php

#
# ...
#
</VirtualHost>
```